# knockout.validation.js error in IE8, observable does not support 'extend' property or method

Tags: validation, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8, extend, observable

Our knockout validation setup works on FF, Chrome, IE 10 and 9. In IE8 we get the error:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'extend' 
knockout.validation.js, line 353 character 17

This is when knockout is trying to add a rule, the observable being passed is a boolean value not a function as it should be. Not sure why a boolean is being passed. We have quite a few constructs like this for e.g.:
self.MiddleInitial = ko.observable().extend({ maxLength: 1 });

if we comment out all of the knockout-extends, then we have no error

related html looks like this:

Site is ASP.Net/MVC. versions: knockout 2.2.1.debug, modernizr-2.6.2, jquery 1.10.1, jquery-ui-1.10.3

Thanks in advance.

It seems the error happens when knockout tries to add a "requires" rule on a set of checkboxes. The related observable does not have any validation specified for it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your observable is binded to a new HTML5 tag and that makes your observable null?

Or a similar issue to do with you relying on some html5 functionality or feature which fails in IE8?

and obviously null or undefined won't have the method extend.

Comment: Thanks, there is something in what you say. IE8 balks at checkboxes generated in a ko foreach template. It assumes something and tries to apply html5 required validation to it and dies. What is making it apply this html5 validation when none is specified is a mystery.

Comment: Here is the ko.validation.config   ko.validation.configure({
        registerExtenders: true,
        errorsAsTitle: true,
        errorsAsTitleOnModified: false,
        decorateElement:true,
        messagesOnModified: true,
        insertMessages: false,
        parseInputAttributes: true,
        messageTemplate: null,
        errorElementClass:'requiredError'
    });

Comment: Setting parseInputAttributes to false in the ko.validation.config fixed the error. Thanks for pointing us in the right direction!